# CSS animation of plane flying onto page and landing

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I'm looking for a way to animate a plane flying from off-page onto the page. At the moment, I'm using the code below, which is very clunky and not smooth.  Do you know a better way to do this using CSS and HTML?  If not, using another method?

```css
.plane-animation{
  animation: animationFrames linear 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation: animationFrames linear 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-animation: animationFrames linear 3s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-animation: animationFrames linear 3s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-animation: animationFrames linear 2s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes animationFrames{
  0% {
    transform:  translate(100%,-20px)  rotate(0deg) ;
  }
  10% {
    transform:  translate(90%,-30px)  rotate(5deg) ;
  }
  20% {
    transform:  translate(80%,-40px)  rotate(15deg) ;
  }
  30% {
    transform:  translate(70%,-50px)  rotate(10deg) ;
  }  
  40% {
    transform:  translate(60%,-60px)  rotate(5deg) ;
  }
  50% {
    transform:  translate(50%,-70px)  rotate(0deg) ;
  }  
  60% {
    transform:  translate(40%,-60px)  rotate(-5deg) ;
  }
  70% {
    transform:  translate(30%,-50px)  rotate(-10deg) ;
  }
  80% {
    transform:  translate(20%,-40px)  rotate(-15deg) ;
  }
  90% {
    transform:  translate(10%,-30px)  rotate(-10deg) ;
  }
  100% {
    transform:  translate(0%,0px)  rotate(0deg) ;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="plane-animation" src="http://www.jetcharterrewards.com/images/Plane%20Icons/plane-icon-4.png" alt="Paper Airplane" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're on the right track, and CSS animations should be perfect for the task you're solving. A few quick pointers:

1. You've made prefixed animation calls like -webkit-, -moz-, -o- and -ms-. However, you've not made any prefixed keyframes. This makes the first part wasted. If you want full browser compatibility you also need prefixed keyframes and prefixed transforms.

Like this:

```
@keyframes animationFrames{
    0% {
        transform:  translate(100%,-20px)  rotate(0deg) ;
    }
    100% {
        transform:  translate(100%,-20px)  rotate(0deg) ;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animationFrames{
    0% {
        -webkit-transform:  translate(100%,-20px)  rotate(0deg) ;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:  translate(100%,-20px)  rotate(0deg) ;
    }
}

....
```

and so on.

2. The other part is more esthetic, but I suggest trying to work on one property at a time. Try drawing your animation in lines on a piece of paper first, figure out the axis and vectors that it's moving on and code one at a time. I'm afraid no-one on here can give you a finished piece of code, but with enough practice, I'm sure you will get the hang of animating.